# Devise Unlock Button in Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This is probably very simple and I'm overlooking it. I am using devise lockable functions and I would like to create a button that an admin can check to unlock a locked user.

Devise has a model method called [unlock_access!](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/547e18e24e7141d65357d97210bcb342161ca2b7/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb). I am trying to call it in my users' controller method with a button in the views.

*Views:*

```
= link_to('unlock', user_unlock_path(user), method: :post, class: 'button-xs') unless user == current_user
```

*users_controller.rb:*

```
def unlock
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.unlock_access!
end
```

*route*

```
resources :users do
  post 'unlock'
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out.

You have to update your route to call the method on a member. Updated the views and controller with working code.

*routes*

```
resources :users do
  post :unlock, :on => :member
end
```

*updated controller*

```
def unlock
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.unlock_access!
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

*updated views*

```
= link_to(t('common.unlock'), unlock_user_path(user), method: :post, class: 'button-xs') unless user == current_user
```

Comment: I would use the patch method (put one for old releases of rails) instead of the post one.

Comment: what is t here?

Comment: It's a helper from Haml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873894/how-to-use-the-haml-t-helper-in-ror

Comment: `t` is the Rails translate function. It's used for localization.