# How to use the HAML t() helper in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm developing an application with Rails 4 and I want to use the helper t() with HAML, but I can not

Example usage:

```
=model_name = @article.class.model_name.human
%h1 Create  t(:model_name)
```

My first line shows me the correct article, but when I use t() it shows me t(:model_name). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope in translational file you have `en.yml`

```
en:
  article: MyArticle
```

Then

```
%h2= t 'article'
```

if you want dynamically

```
%h2= t '#{model_name}'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, other question if i want add a message? for example Create and after the model_name?

Comment: If it is worked please accept my answer yes you can add it easily like `%h2= t('#{model_name}') + 'created'` or `%h2= t('article') + 'created'`

Comment: Excellent, Thank you :)